# Jest: Wait for called .then of async method in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, async-await, jestjs

I am currently stuck on writing a test of my React-App.

I have an async call in my componentDidMount method and are updating the state after returning. However, I do not get this to work.

I have found several solutions and None seems to work as expected. Below is the nearest point I have come to.

App:

```
class App extends Component<{}, IState> {
    state: IState = {
        fetchedData: false
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        await thing.initialize();
        this.test();
    }

    test = () => {
        this.setState({ fetchedData: true })
    };

    render() {
        return this.state.fetchedData ? (
            <div>Hello</div>
        ) : (
            <Spinner />
        );
    }
}
```

The test

```
it('Base test for app', async () => {
    const spy = spyOn(thing, 'initialize').and.callThrough();  // just for debugging
    const wrapper = await mount(<App />);
    // await wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();  // With this it works, but componentDidMount is called twice.
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.find('Spinner').length).toBe(0);
});
```

Well, so...thing.initialize is called (it is an async method that fetches some stuff).
If I do explicitly call wrapper.instance().componentDidMount() then it will work, but componentDidMount will be called twice.

Here are my ideas that I have tried but None succeeded:

- Spying on thing.initialize() -> I did not find out how I proceed with the test *after* the method has been called and finished.
- Spying on App.test -> The same here
- Working with promises instead of async await
- At the beginning, I had an thing.initialize().then(this.test) in my componentDidMount

It can't be much, but can someone tell me which piece I am missing?

Comment: do you really need keep `thing.initialize()` to be real call? to me test's code looks fine(actually you don't need `wrapper.update()`) but it will work only if `thing.initialize()` immediately resolves/rejects. if it's a really call with non-zero delay your test is finishing before response comes.

Comment: Yes, the test goes on before app.test is called, this is exactly the problem. Thing.initialize is an asynchronous function that fetches some data and stores it in localstorage. Therefore it does not (and I think cannot) return immediately.

Comment: is it unit test or integration test?

Comment: I want to test a page of my app that is rendered after initialization. What I could do as an alternative is to create a component of the stuff that is rendered after the initialization, and test this after explicitly calling thing.initialize. But I think this would be a workaround for something that should work somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is **integration test** you better to follow *awaiting* approach that say Selenium use: that is, just wait until some element appears or timeout reached. How it should be coded depends on library you use(for Puppeter it should be [waitForSelector](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options)).

Once it's about **unit test** then I suggest you different approach:

1. mock every single external dependencies with `Promise` you control(by your code it's hard to say if [automatic mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock) will work or you need to compose [mock factory](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-docs-en-jest-object-jestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter) but one of them or both will help)
2. initialize element(I mean just run `shallow()` or `mount()`)
3. await till your mocks are resolved(with extra `await`, using `setTimeout(... ,0)` or [`flush-promises`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flush-promises) will work, check [how microtasks/macrotasks works](https://abc.danch.me/microtasks-macrotasks-more-on-the-event-loop-881557d7af6f))
4. assert against element's `render` and check if your mocks has been called

And finally:

1. setting state directly
2. mocking/spying on internal methods
3. verifying against state

are all lead to unstable test since it's implementation details you should not worry about during unit-testing. And it's hard to work with them anyway.

So your test would look like:

```
import thing from '../thing';
import Spinner from '../../Spinner';
import flushPromises from 'flush-promises';

it('loads data and renders it', async () => {
  jest.mock('../thing'); // thing.implementation is already mocked with jest.fn()
  thing.initialize.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(/*data you expect to return*/));
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  expect(wrapper.find(Spinner)).toHaveLength(1);
  expect(wrapper.find(SomeElementYouRenderWithData)).toHaveLength(0);
  await flushPromises();
  expect(wrapper.find(Spinner)).toHaveLength(0);
  expect(wrapper.find(SomeElementYouRenderWithData)).toHaveLength(1);
})
```

or you may test how component behaves on rejection:

```
import thing from '../thing';
import Spinner from '../../Spinner';
import flushPromises from 'flush-promises';

it('renders error message on loading failuer', async () => {
  jest.mock('../thing'); // thing.implementation is already mocked with jest.fn()
  thing.initialize.mockReturnValue(Promise.reject(/*some error data*/));
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  expect(wrapper.find(Spinner)).toHaveLength(1);
  await flushPromises();
  expect(wrapper.find(Spinner)).toHaveLength(0);
  expect(wrapper.find(SomeElementYouRenderWithData)).toHaveLength(0);
  expect(wrapper.find(SomeErrorMessage)).toHaveLength(1);
})
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. It is not exactly what was my idea, since I did not want to mock the thing.initialize.
But I can test that separately and call the initialization now once before all tests which will safe time.